# Making two cases together in inputting data on certain sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I've been working for awhile on a visual calendar for project management. The calendar takes the userform:
[image: UserForm]

I currently have a code set in place to filter the data to the appropriate sheet based on what value they choose for "Impact" -- either "High" or "Low"

On pressing "Enter Project"

```
Private Sub enterButton_Click()

    If Not CheckInputs Then Exit Sub 'check for fields to have values
    Process GetWs(Me.impactCombobox.Value) ' process data passing the proper worksheet got from GetWs() function
    MsgBox "Project Entered Successfully"
    ClearUFData 'clear the data
```

The GetWS Function:

```
Function GetWs(impact As String) As Worksheet
    Select Case impact
        Case "High"
            Set GetWs = Worksheets("HI Project Work Database")
        Case "Low"
            Set GetWs = Worksheets("LI Project Work Database")
'        Case Else
    End Select
End Function
```

How would I go about embedding in another case that is specific for the option buttons of "Project Work" and "Implementation?"

For example:

High Impact - Project Work = Spreadsheet "HI Project Work Database"

Low Impact - Project Work = Spreadsheet "LI Project Work Database"

High Impact - Implementation = Spreadsheet "HI Implementation Database"

Low Impact - Implementation = Spreadsheet "LI Implementation Database"

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this.

```
Function GetWs(impact As String) As Worksheet
    Select Case impact
        Case "High"
            Select Case True
                Case ProjectWorkOption.Value = True
                    Set GetWs = Worksheets("HI Project Work Database")
                Case ImplementationOption.Value = True
                    Set GetWs = Worksheets("HI Implementation Database")
            End Select
        Case "Low"
            Select Case True
                Case ProjectWorkOption.Value = True
                    Set GetWs = Worksheets("LI Project Work Database")
                Case ImplementationOption.Value = True
                    Set GetWs = Worksheets("LI Implementation Database")
            End Select
    End Select
End Function
```

Obviously you need to swap out the names of your option buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `If` to your `Select Case`.
Assume your `User_Form` name is **User_Form1**. the code below will fit you :

```
Function GetWs(impact As String) As Worksheet
    Select Case impact
        Case "High"
            If UserForm1.Project_Work.Value = True Then
                Set GetWs = Worksheets("HI Project Work Database")
            Else
                If UserForm1.Implementation.Value = True Then
                    Set GetWs = Worksheets("HI Implementation Database")
                End If

            End If
        Case "Low"
            If UserForm1.Project_Work.Value = True Then
                Set GetWs = Worksheets("LI Project Work Database")
            Else
                If UserForm1.Implementation.Value = True Then
                    Set GetWs = Worksheets("LI Implementation Database")
                End If
            End If

'        Case Else

    End Select
End Function
```